# very strange C++ error

Tags: c++

I have encountered a very strange problem when I am writing code, Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int qnum;
    cin >> qnum;
    int series[3];
    cin >> series[3];
    cout << qnum;
}
```

For example, If I input 2 for qnum and 5 for series[3], The value of qnum will be overridden in the last line of code.This problem will only occurs when the input for series is 3. The only solution for new is add "static" attribute to qnum, Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static int qnum;
    cin >> qnum;
    int series[3];
    cin >> series[3];
    cout << qnum;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You count in C++ starting at 0.  So the last valid index into series is series[2]

Comment: You should compile your code with all warnings enabled. Every decent compiler should warn about something like this.

Comment: @pmr: Depends on your definition of a "decent" compiler, I suppose.  GCC doesn't with `-Wall -Wextra` (though perhaps there is some other more obscure flag that enables detection of this, though).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Strange. It doesn't warn in this case, but it warns with your settings and `-O2` for assignment.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `series[3]`.  There are only `series[0]`, `series[1]` and `series[2]` (arrays go from 0 to N-1).

You are writing off the end of your array, which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm a newbie,sorry for asking such stupid questiuon.

Comment: Oh snap, I knew it was a buffer overwrite somewhere but I didn't notice that he was writing to the forth element of a 3-count array.